# webpage overflow scroll bar

Tags: html, css

Here is the issue I am having:

One of my webpages overflows on the x-axis, meaning I have to scroll left or right which in effect causes other issues.

I started disabling all the css stuff for that page, but I still continue to see the scroll bar at the bottom.

How do I find out which element/html code is causing this? There are literally hundreds of lines of code.

Thanks
Bruce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a WebKit-based browser, try the Web Inspector. If you're using Firefox, try using Firebug.

Regardless, either of those tools should have some way that lets you see the HTML of the page. In both of these tools, when you hover over the element in the inspector, it will highlight the element on the page. If you just move your mouse down over the elements, you might see one pop out of the confines of the page. If that doesn't find it, you could try right clicking on areas of the normally-out-of-view part and clicking Inspect Element. If you get some specific element, that might be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browser you are using, there are multiple methods via an 'element inspector'.  A helpful bookmarklet that I have found is [XRAY](http://www.westciv.com/xray/).  Simply enable the inspector or bookmarklet and simply highlight the designated area that you wish to inspect.